# Record audio with another header than caf

Tags: ios, swift, avaudiorecorder, opus, caf

I want to record audio in Opus format on iOS share it with other clients. I did this using this setting for AVAudioRecorder:

```
let audioRecorderSettings = [AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
                             AVFormatIDKey : kAudioFormatOpus,
                             AVSampleRateKey: 16000.0] as [String : Any]
```

but now other non-Apple devices are not able to playing my ".ogg" file that I have recorded and I found that the file header is "caf" unlike other Opus format files.
I just want to make my recorded file readable for other devices like Android devices. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Did you find the answer how to play recorded opus audio in iOS on Android

Comment: I did it by importing ogg/opus C framework to my project. Found it in Telegram source code (on GitHub). I think it is not possible to do that with native iOS solutions.